# Compressing audio files similar to transfer from server to client

Tags: audio, compression, audio-streaming

In my project, I need to be able to compress small audio files so that it can be transferred easily from server to the client. I found We Chat uses audio compression closest to my requirement. But I couldn't find ways of doing it

I'm able to write code for image compression by reducing resolution and clarity. What should I try here ? combine two frames into one etc. Streaming is definitely possible if two frames are mixed into one. I want to know if there are any well developed libraries to do the same. I'm easy on the format until client side is able to read it. I also want to know if streaming is possible in compressed format.

Comment: Is this an academic, hobby, or commercial project? There are lots of audio compression options that vary greatly in complexity.

Comment: This is academic right now, but I want to learn in industry standards.. If there is anywhere I could start to learn about different technologies, it would be great

Answer (score 1):

I run [a wiki that deals with the specifics of all kinds of multimedia technology](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/). You might be interested in the [Audio Codecs category](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=Category%3aAudio_Codecs), currently cataloging about 150 different audio codecs.

I can't tell from your question if you control both the client and server, or if you only control the server. If you control both, try a simple [IMA ADPCM variant](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=IMA_ADPCM) in order to get started. If you don't control the client, then of course your will need to code towards whatever the client can support.

There are many more codecs, of course, and lots of them have existing open source implementations that you may wish to leverage.